# Using the name of an "AS" column in the WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, select

I have the following query in mysql:

```
SELECT voter_id, first, middle, last, title, party, phone, ward, 
households.hh_id, households.hh_long, voters.1311 + voters.1111 + 
voters.0911 + voters.0909 + voters.1109 AS muni_score 
FROM voters 
JOIN households on voters.hh_id = households.hh_id 
WHERE muni_score >= 3 AND phone <> ''
```

I get the following error:

`Unknown column 'muni_score' in 'where clause'`

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you have is that the where clause is executed before the Select clause of a query, so when it hits the where section it has no concept of what the muni_score is

There are two simple workarounds (not taking any performance into account here) and I'll note down a slightly more complex one.

The easiest is to simply replace the muni_score in the where clause with what makes is up, so:

```
WHERE (voters.1311 + voters.1111 + voters.0911 + voters.0909 + voters.1109) >= 3
AND phone <>''
```

The other simple way is to put in a sub query as @dnoeth suggests in his answer

The slightly more complex way is to instead of using a sub query putting the data you want into a view and then querying from that:

```
CREATE VIEW Voters_Households_noPhone AS
SELECT voter_id, first, middle, last, title, party, phone, ward, households.hh_id, households.hh_long, voters.1311 + voters.1111 + voters.0911 + voters.0909 + voters.1109 AS muni_score FROM voters JOIN households on voters.hh_id = households.hh_id WHERE phone <> ''
```

Then any time you wish to get that exact query you can run (don't select * though)

```
SELECT * FROM Voters_Households_noPhone WHERE muni_score >= 3
```

(And you can do other values in there aswell)

There will be many other things you can try, but as mentioned initially the problem is when a query is ran, the SELECT part almost right at the end so you can't use that anywhere else in the query unforutnatly

EDIT: Select doesn't come dead last in a query, full execution order for reference is:
FROM-ON(JOIN)-OUTER-WHERE- GROUP BY-CUBE/ROLLUP-HAVING-SELECT-DISTINCT-ORDER BY-TOP

Answer (score 4):

To refer to an alias you need a Derived Table:

```
SELECT *
FROM
 (
   SELECT voter_id, first, middle, last, title, party, phone, ward, 
      households.hh_id, households.hh_long,
      voters.1311 + voters.1111 + voters.0911 + voters.0909 + voters.1109 AS muni_score 
   FROM voters
   JOIN households
     on voters.hh_id = households.hh_id 
   WHERE phone <> '' 
 ) as dt
WHERE muni_score >= 3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE muni_score >= 3 AND phone <> ''
```

-->

```
WHERE phone <> ''
HAVING muni_score >= 3
```

Aliases are not available until after `WHERE` is done.  This is important to aggregates used with `GROUP BY`, but it also applies in your case.

The alternative is to spell out the expression (again) in the `WHERE`.

Comment: I think using `HAVING` is better than create a `VIEW` or make the same computed field in the `WHERE`.